# How to add image in an fragment, with parallax effect?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to add an image at the top of a fragment, it should have parallax effect when scrolled to view image details.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpejW.png)

I tried to get this using collapsible toolbar, but the issue is that the image is not filling the whole toolbar leaving blank space on sideways if image is in portrait mode. and also no parallax is there.

This is the xml code of what I have done till now.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="70dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/actionbarlayout"
        android:layout_height="207dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbarLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:id="@+id/details_Image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/new_order"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/download"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_file_download_white_36dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/favourite"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1">


                                <ImageButton
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/zoom"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_ic_zoom_out_map_white_36dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    />

                            </RelativeLayout>



                        </LinearLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
                            android:text="Sample text"

                            />



                    </ScrollView>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/fullimage"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[This is what it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNRoh.png)

Please suggest me what changes I need to make in order to attain what I want, thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Use `match_parent` for ImageView and `centerCrop` for scale type.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working that way too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for the `ImageView`

Comment: no, it's not working, can it be because of any limitation to the maximum height that a collapsible toolbar can be?

Comment: what UI do you get when you use that....I'm using that here (`CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and it's working).

Comment: @User9132 Set layout_height of imageView as match_parent and scaleType as centerCrop

Comment: @KartikSharma, it's still the same.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, it's working when Image is not that long, the image fills the collapsible toolbar without any problem, but when the image is long, blank spaces are there.